Question regarding a proof of density of smooth functions on $(0,T)\times\Omega$ in $W(0,T)$
I have a questions regarding the (accepted) proof of the density on the product space in (Density of smooth functions on $(0,T)\times\Omega$ in $W(0,T)$).
The question relates to the statement that the partial sums convergence uniformly with respect to $t ∈ [0, T]$: $\sum_{n=1}^N \langle u(t), e_n\rangle\phi_n = u_N \to u_{\epsilon} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \langle u(t), e_n\rangle\phi_n $ in $L^{\infty}(0,T;H^1)$ as $N \to \infty$. How can I justify that?
Many thanks!

The infinite sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle u,e_n\rangle \phi_n$ converges in $L^\infty(0,T;H^1)$, hence the convergence of the partial sums. Here, $u$ is already smooth in time.

Thx and sorry for my late feedback. So, from the convergence $u_\epsilon \to u$ in $L^{\infty}(0,T;H^1)$ I see that all $u_\epsilon$ are well defined in $L^{\infty}(0,T;H^1)$ and thus the limit of the partial sums also, and to see the convergence of the partial sums in $L^{\infty}(0,T;H^1)$ I use that every partial sum is an element of $L^{\infty}(0,T;H^1)$ by the smoothness of $u$ and the intervall being compact. Do I understand correctly?

I added an detailed answer. The arguments I had in mind to prove the convergence did not work ...

Let $u \in C([0,T], H^1_0)$ with $(e_n)$ a complete orthonormal system of $H^1_0$.
Then for each $t\in [0,T]$ we have
$$
u(t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle u(t),e_n\rangle e_n
$$
(where the series converges in $H^1$)
and $\| u(t) \|_{H^1}^2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty|\langle u(t),e_n\rangle|^2$.
Define
$$
u_N (t) :=  \sum_{n=1}^N \langle u(t),e_n\rangle e_n.
$$
Then
$$
\| u(t) - u_N(t) \|_{H^1}^2 \le \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty  |\langle u(t),e_n\rangle|^2.
$$
The right-hand side converges to zero for $N\to \infty$, hence we have the pointwise convergence $u_N(t) \to u(t)$ in $H^1$. It remains to prove that we have uniform convergence. The convergence is uniform if the following claim has been proven:

Claim: $$\lim_{N\to\infty} \sup_{t\in [0,T]} \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty  |\langle u(t),e_n\rangle|^2=0$$

Proof: Suppose not. Then there is $\epsilon>0$, and for each $N$ (or at least for infinitely many $N$) there is $t_N \in [0,T]$ such that $\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty  |\langle u(t_N),e_n\rangle|^2 \ge \epsilon$.
Since $[0,T]$ is compact, we can assume $t_N \to t$ (after extracting a subsequence).
Now let $M>0$ be such that
$$\sum_{n=M+1}^\infty  |\langle u(t),e_n\rangle|^2 < \frac\epsilon8.$$
Since $u \in C([0,T],H^1)$, we have $\|u(t)-u(t_N)\|_{H^1}^2 \le \frac\epsilon8$ for $N>M$ sufficiently large.
This implies
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty  |\langle u(t)-u(t_N),e_n\rangle|^2 < \frac\epsilon8.
$$
Then
$$
\epsilon \le \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty  |\langle u(t_N),e_n\rangle|^2 
\le \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty  |\langle u(t_N)-u(t)+u(t),e_n\rangle|^2 
\le 2 \left( \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty  |\langle u(t_N)-u(t),e_n\rangle|^2  + \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty  |\langle u(t),e_n\rangle|^2 \right)
\le \frac\epsilon2
$$
leads to a contradiction.

This proves $u_N \to u$ in $C([0,T],H^1)$.

Fix $\epsilon>0$. Then for each $n$ take $\phi_n$ such that $\| \phi_n - e_n\| \le 2^{-n}\epsilon$.
Define
$$
u_{N,\epsilon}:=  \sum_{n=1}^N \langle u(t),e_n\rangle \phi_n.
$$
For the tail of the difference of sums $u_N$ and $u_{N,\epsilon}$ we have the following estimate
$$
\| \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \langle u(t),e_n\rangle (e_n-\phi_n) \|_{H^1}
\le \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty|\langle u(t),e_n\rangle|  2^{-n}\epsilon
\le \left( \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty |\langle u(t),e_n\rangle| ^2 \right)^{1/2}
\cdot \epsilon.
$$
As proven above, the right-hand side converges to zero uniformly for $N\to \infty$. Then the limit $\lim_{N\to \infty} u_N- u_{N,\epsilon}$
exists in $C([0,T,H^1)$, and then also
the infinite series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle u(t),e_n\rangle \phi_n= \lim_{N\to \infty}u_{N,\epsilon}
$$
converges in $C([0,T,H^1)$.

After thinking more about this problem: the set ${ u(t) : t\in [0,T]}$ is compact, and then the series $u(t) = \sum_n \langle u(t),e_n\rangle e_n$ converges uniformly in $t$.

Many thanks for carrying out in this detail. 1) I think I would have believed you already with $\lVert u(t) - u_N(t)\rVert {H^1} \le \sum{n=N+1}^{\infty} \lvert\langle u(t), e_n\rangle\rvert^2$ since for the right-hand side I guess I could justify uniform convergence for the whole series using Dini's theorem. 2) Isn't the above inequality indeed an equality? I think it comes e.g. from the proof of Bessels/Parseval?

Yes, it is an equality. And thanks for the mention of the Dini theorem: this is the argument that was missing.

Great, thx. Do you see any issue transferring the result into a different setting like, instead of $H^1_0$, e.g. $H^1_D$, i.e. the space of $H^1$ functions vanishing at some part of the boundary (as long as this is a Hilbert space on its own) or even it's dual $(H^1_D)^*$?

Any separable Hilbert space works.

This really helps. Thanks for the discussion!
